# How can I play an .flv file on Android 2.1?

Tags: video, media-player

I would like to play an .flv movie file on Android 2.1. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you have a problem with the apps found with an Android Market search for "flv" or similar?  If I don't see a real problem here (required as per the [FAQ]), this is just an off-topic recommendation question.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few FLV players available on Android, try among these: [13 Great Video Players for Android](http://mobiputing.com/2011/08/12-great-video-players-for-android/). The Mobo Player seems promising among them.

Here's a link for [Mobo Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil) as well, just in case. :)